# Audit and prevent users from deleting public list views - sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, permissions, list-view, auditing

We have a SharePoint 2010 site that contains a list, available to different users with different permissions level, ranging from Read to Contribute.

Few days ago, someone who doesn't confess, removed 2 of the public views.

1. Is it possible to limit users so they will only be able to view and edit List-Public-Views, without having permissions to delete a public view? if not, what is my next best option?
2. Is there any way to log and audit when users edit and delete list personal views?
3. Can I restore a List public view?

Answer (score 0):

1. A user with Contribute permissions cannot delete a public view. They need at least Design permissions to do that. Be sure to check the permissions on the list, since it may not inherit the perms from the parent site.
2. don't know that one
3. Why don't you restore the view from your backups? Also, a list view should not be too hard to create. List views are not that complex, and they can only ***show*** the data, not modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
1. i will check that once again
3. Do you mean - rollback - our site to an older version together with all the data the was added to the site lists etc etc..?